# Receive money in regtest mode

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, regtest

I am working on a app in which my project communicates with the bitcoin server to get the details of a transaction with transaction id as the parameter. I have bitcoind, bitcoin-cli and bitcoin-qt installed on my system. When I run the bitcoin-qt in regtest mode, I am able to create test transactions in which I can send money to an address and get the transaction id for the same. I use this transaction id in my app, I am able to get the transaction details from bitcoin-qt. The problem is, now my testing is limited to only outward transactions wherein I transfer bitcoins to another account. How can I create some test transactions wherein bitcoins are credited to my wallet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to run multiple `bitcoind` instances in `regtest` to simulate multiple nodes.
Thats pretty easy. You can run a second instance by starting bitcoind with a clean data directory and a different RPC and P2P port.

For that, you could create a 2nd data directory (example: `/tmp/datadir2`). Create `/tmp/datadir2/bitcoin.conf`.

Use something similar than:

```
regtest=1
rpcuser=rt
rpcuser=rt
port=12340
rpcport=10340
discover=0
```

Now you need to connect your first node with your 2nd node by sending a `addnode` over the RPC interface.

```
bitcoin-cli addnode 127.0.0.1:10340 onetry
```

You can than distinct between both nodes with the `-datadir` argument while calling `bitcoin-cli`.

```
bitcoin-cli -datadir=/tmp/datadir2/ getinfo
```

### Some examples:

**generate coins in first node (50 BTC available)**

```
bitcoin-cli generate 101
```

**get address from 2nd node**

```
bitcoin-cli -datadir=/tmp/datadir2/ getnewaddress
```

**send coins to 2nd node**

```
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <address> 10.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had done the exact same thing and got it running. I was setting the datadir on my  host system to a separate directory when starting bitcoin-qt. This was somehow preventing my app from talking with bitcoin-qt.

Comment: After doing the above, when I do `getmempoolinfo` for the node that receives the transaction, it still shows 0. How do I send the transaction over.

Comment: Maybe the received funds are not yet confirmed,... call a generate(1) again or try to list unconfirmed balance

Comment: I am trying to use the same above script but its adding the following error to the log

2019-01-10T12:35:51Z Binding RPC on address ::1 port 18443 failed.
2019-01-10T12:35:51Z Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 18443 failed.
2019-01-10T12:35:51Z Unable to bind any endpoint for RPC server
2019-01-10T12:35:51Z Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.
2019-01-10T12:35:51Z Shutdown: In progress...

Comment: For the record, starting at 0.18 the command `generate` is deprecated and in 0.19 it will be completely removed. Use `generatetoaddress` instead.